# How to get outer HTML/Tag from a given String?

Tags: php, html, regex, xpath, scrape

i don't know if this is even possible (i guess, but cannot say if or if not) but how can i get the outer html of a given string in php?
Lets say you want to grab the price of a product in a webshop where the html code is as follows:

```
<span class="product">3,47 €</span>
```

I do know how to grab the price, but i want to save the position to keep track of the price. If i want to grab it next week again i don't want to find the position again, so i want to save it somehow.

Is there a function or regex to check what tag the given string is surrounded? saving the xpath of the tag would be also great.

I hope my english is understandable, as english is not my mother tongue.

Thank you very much for your help.

Daniel

Comment: How did you get the price in the first place?

Comment: I use regex to find all possible prices and let the user decide which price is the one he is looking for. (/\d+(?:\,\d{2})(?:\$|\£|\€|\EUR)?/)

Comment: How are you reading the XML? DOMNode has a method getNodePath(), actually.

Answer (score 1):

```
function rip_tags($string) { 

$string = preg_replace ('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $string); 
return $string; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think you misunderstood what i meant. i don't want to strip the tags out. i want to know what is around my string (div) or to get the xpath from the string